# Custom jScrollPane scroll bar can be dragged too low

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

I'm creating a custom jScrollPane scroll bar and I'm having trouble figuring out a way to limit the vertical drag distance to keep it from scrolling below where the div cuts off.

See http://jsfiddle.net/wE8ry/

```
body
{
background: black;
}

.scroll-pane
{
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
overflow: auto;
background: black;
color: white;
}

.jspContainer
{
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.jspPane
{
position: absolute;
}

.jspVerticalBar
{
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
right: 3px;
width: 5px;
height: 100%;
background: red;
}

.jspHorizontalBar
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
background: red;
}

.jspVerticalBar *,
.jspHorizontalBar *
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.jspCap
{
display: none;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspCap
{
float: left;
}

.jspTrack
{
background: black;
position: relative;
}

.jspDrag
{
background: #fccb00;
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
cursor: pointer;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #985400;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #985400;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #985400;

}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspTrack,
.jspHorizontalBar .jspDrag
{
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

.jspArrow
{
background: #50506d;
text-indent: -20000px;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.jspArrow.jspDisabled
{
cursor: default;
background: #80808d;
}

.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow
{
height: 16px;
}

.jspHorizontalBar .jspArrow
{
width: 16px;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow:focus
{
outline: none;
}

.jspCorner
{
background: #eeeef4;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the jscrollpane JavaScript and added a setting to cut the drag distance short by a specified number of pixels. This works but isn't ideal. A better idea would be to add a dropshadow option and update all of the calculations/css based on it and submit it as a patch.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue stems from the change you made on the .jspdrag:
`box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #985400;`

I assume your hack was for exactly 4 pixels.

Comment: It did. See the comment under my post...that fixed it. I was just wondering whether there was a way that works without editing the code, but I don't think there is.

Comment: well, you could edit the CSS instead of the code, right? Add the padding in a different way?

Comment: It's been quite a while since I've worked on this project, but I believe there was code in the JavaScript that changed the CSS properties. Sorry that I can't remember the specifics, but if it's of interest to anyone I will look into it some more.